# Vue 3 props property not updating

Tags: vue.js

I have parent component like below:

```
<template>
  <button @click="initStr" value="init str" />
  <child :str="str" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: { child, },
  setup() {
    const str= ref("");
    function initStr() {
      str.value = "init";
    }

    return {
      str,
      initStr,
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

The problem is when click the button on parent to init string, the child component does not rerender with the new string. I have to create another ref varible in child component then watch the props to assign the new string like below:

```
const string = ref(props.str);
watch(props, props => {
  string.value = props.str;
});
```

Is this the only way to rerender the child when props from parent changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work as shown in the following example :

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue;
const App = {

  setup() {
    const str = Vue.ref("");

    function initStr() {
      str.value = "init";
    }

    return {
      str,
      initStr,
    };
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.component('child', {
  props: ['str'],
  template: `
<div> str : {{str}}</div>
`
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="initStr">
   init str
  </button>
  <child :str="str" />
</div>
```